# What does y_test[0] means exactly?

Tags: machine-learning

why y_test[0] works fine here

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = lr.predict(X_test)

print("Actual value of the house:- ", y_test[0]) 
print("Model Predicted Value:- ", predictions[0])
```

but y_test[1] can't.

here shape of y_test shape is (102,)

so by the array logic it should give me value upto 102.

y_test[0]
y_test[1]
.
.
.
.
.
y_test[102]

but only y_test[0] works.

I thought y_test[1] should work the same as y_test[0] but something is wrong with that idk what.
what does y_test[0] means exactly?

Comment: What does it happens when you enter `y_test[1]`? If there's an error, what's the error message? Maybe `KeyError: 1`?

Comment: BTW, if y_test has 102 elements, it should index up to `y_test[101]`.

Comment: It's a key error

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly yes

Comment: Probably there's no y_test with index 1, maybe that index number went to the training split?